# Node Js : MYSQL is not connecting

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am new to node.js, so i am stuck at this point. I have tried to learn it from these sites [Code Mentor](https://www.codementor.io/nodejs/tutorial/node-js-mysql) and [Github](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql)

Till now i have done this :

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var app = express();

// Database operations
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host : 'localhost',
  port : '8888',
  user : 'sharad',
  password : 'teks',
  dbName : 'FirstDataBase'
});

connection.connect(function (error) {
  if (error){
    console.error('error connecting :' + error.stack);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Connected as id :'+ connection.threadId);
});

app.get("/",function(request,response){
  console.log(' saving');
  var post  = {from:'me', to:'you', msg:'hi'};
  connection.query('INSERT INTO FirstDataBase SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
});

app.get("/",function(request,response){
  connection.query('SELECT * from FirstDataBase', function(err, rows, fields) {
    connection.end();
    if (!err)
      console.log('The solution is: ', rows);
    else
      console.log('Error while performing Query.');
  });
});

app.listen(8888);
```

I can not see any log i am printing in my code. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

**Edits :**

Error i get if i remove last line `app.listen(8888);`

```
error connecting :Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:907:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:930:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1077:14)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/Users/Admin/IdeaProjects/FirstNodeJS/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:141:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/Users/Admin/IdeaProjects/FirstNodeJS/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:41)
    at Connection.connect (/Users/Admin/IdeaProjects/FirstNodeJS/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:136:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Admin/IdeaProjects/FirstNodeJS/app.js:40:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
```

Comment: Are `mysql` running on your localhost? can you check it on console?

Comment: sorry, i dont know how to check it. can you give some idea ?

Comment: i get this I get "sudo: mysql: command not found" so i guess it is not.

Comment: Try this on your console and check `mysql --user=your usrname --password=your password` mysql server is started or not

Comment: i am installing MAMP now, i dont have sql i think.

Comment: You can also check there and make sure your `mysql` server is started

Comment: What is ` port : '8888',` in your mysql configuration

Comment: port for local host

Comment: no need to give port in mysql configuration check the doc https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql

Comment: yeah i didn't give any port first, then it was throwing error. it need a ports on which localhost server is running.

Comment: Can you post error here?

Comment: okay see my edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem by installing MAMP and using fields provided by MAMP.

[image: MAMP fields]

[image: Updated code]

Comment: I also use MAMP. You saved my day, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I resolve this issue like this

install mysql:

npm install mysql

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

let connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    port: '8888',  /* port on which phpmyadmin run */
    password: 'root',
    database: 'dbname',
    socketPath: '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' //for mac and linux
});

connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error('error: ' + err.message);
    }

    console.log('Connected to the MySQL server.');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
 host     : 'localhost',
 user     : 'xxxxx',
 password : 'xxxxx',
 database : 'xxx'
 });
connection.connect();
```